# KeyPress Visual Basic - Cursor nach Eingabe in TextBox setzen

Tags: vb.net, textbox, cursor, keypress

I would like the following to be caught when typing into a TextBox:

- The result must always look like this: X-70-XXXXX-XXX
- The first X is a letter The 5 XXXXX must be numbers
- The last three XXX must be a letter + numbers (e.g.: B23)

The catching is no problem. But now I want the -70- to be automatically appended to the first letter "S" after typing it. Unfortunately, it sets the cursor incorrectly so that the result is (-70-S)
Code:

```
Private Sub TB_Nr_Keypress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TB_Nr.KeyPress
    Dim temp As String
    Dim zaehlen As Integer
    temp = TB_Nr.Text
    zaehlen = TB_Nr.Text.Length
    Try
        Select Case zaehlen
            Case 0
                If e.KeyChar = "S" Or e.KeyChar = "M" Then
                    temp = temp + "-70-"
                    TB_Nr.Text = temp
                    TB_Nr.SelectionStart = TB_Nr.TextLength
                Else
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
            Case Else
                e.Handled = True
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Fehler")
    End Try
End Sub
```

TB_Nr.SelectionStart = TB_Nr.TextLength Does not work. It only sees the content of the text box, which in this case is -70- and not my input, i.e. the letter "S".

What can I do here?

2:

```
.......
        Select Case zaehlen
            Case 0
                If e.KeyChar = "S" Or e.KeyChar = "M" Then
                   temp.Text = e.KeyChar & "-70-"
                    temp.SelectionStart = temp.Text.Length
      e.Handled = True
                Else
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
.....
Case 9 
Select Case Asc(e.KeyChar)
                   Case 48 To 57
                           temp.Text = e.KeyChar & "-"
                       temp.SelectionStart = temp.Text.Length
                        e.Handled = True 
......
```

Comment: This is an English-only site. Please post all questions and answers in English only.

Comment: I would like the following to be caught when typing into a TextBox: The result must always look like this: X-70-XXXXX-XXX
The first X is a letter 
The 5 XXXXX must be numbers 
The last three XXX must be a letter + numbers (e.g.: B23).

The catching is no problem. But now I want the -70- to be automatically appended to the first letter "S" after typing it. Unfortunately, it sets the cursor incorrectly so that the result is (-70-S) See Code above

Comment: TB_Nr.SelectionStart = TB_Nr.TextLength Does not work. It only sees the content of the text box, which in this case is -70- and not my input, i.e. the letter "S".
What can I do here?

Comment: Can you not just use a `MaskedTextBox`?

Comment: Good Idea, but how can I allow, for example, that only the letters A, K & F are allowed in the 5 position?

Comment: L>-7\0-00000-L>00
This is my MaskedTextBox

How can I define here that only certain letters are possible?

Comment: You can't limit to specific characters in a `MaskedTextBox`. You can only limit to specific types of characters. You can still validate input in real time in the same way as you can in a regular `TextBox` though.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `TextLength` after you have set your final text. Your variable has what is before that.

Try this:

```
Private Sub TB_Nr_Keypress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TB_Nr.KeyPress
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Try
        If tb.Text = "" Then
            Select Case e.KeyChar
                Case "S", "M"
                    tb.Text = e.KeyChar & "-70-"
                    tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length
                    e.Handled = True
            End Select
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Fehler")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You! 
But how can I continue to do it?
After the first input I would like to 
S-70-12345- make a dash again 

The following does not work:

Comment: .......
        Select Case zaehlen
            Case 0
                If e.KeyChar = "S" Or e.KeyChar = "M" Then
                   temp.Text = e.KeyChar & "-70-"
                    temp.SelectionStart = temp.Text.Length
      e.Handled = True
                Else
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
.....
Case 9 
Select Case Asc(e.KeyChar)
                   Case 48 To 57
                           temp.Text = e.KeyChar & "-"
                       temp.SelectionStart = temp.Text.Length
                        e.Handled = True 
......

Comment: You would be better off using a `MaskedTextBox` control with its `Mask` property set to `L-7\0-00000-L00` .